# Report Query - variable nr of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which "indexes" the captured documents for an employer's employees.  Each document has got a unique ID, a URI, date captured, staffid (FK) and a document type column named "tag"

```
gv2=# \d staffdoc
                Table "zoozooland_789166.staffdoc"
   Column   |            Type             |       Modifiers       
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------
 id         | uuid                        | not null
 asseturi   | text                        | not null
 created    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 created_by | uuid                        | not null
 tag        | text                        | not null
 is_active  | boolean                     | not null default true
 staffid    | uuid                        | not null
Foreign-key constraints:
    "staffdoc_staffid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (staffid) REFERENCES staffmember(id)
Inherits: assetdoc
```

I want to write a report that will be used to highlight missing documents.

For each staffmember the report should have a column for each document tag type, so the nr of columns is unknown up front.

Currently I do all of this in the application - generate a list of all possible tags (`SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM table`), generate a list of all possible staff-IDs, then for each staff ID I run multiple queries to get the document with the biggest value in the created column for each tag value.

I'm pretty sure I should at least be able to optimise it to one query per document type (tag value) (most recent document for each staff id) which would be a good-enough optimisation.

The typical scenario is 4 or 5 document tag values (document types) so running 5 queries is much more acceptable that running 5 X nr-of-staff queries.

In the final report I have the following columns:

```
 Staff-member Name, doctype1, doctype2, doctype2, etc
```

The name is "joined" from the staffmember table.  The value in the doctype columns is the LAST (MAX) value of dates for that doc tag for that staff member, or "None" if the document is missing for that staffmember.

FWIW I'm using Postgres 9.5

Comment: Sample output would be helpful.